# In Powershell, is there a better way to store/find data in an n-dimensional array than a custom object

Tags: powershell, data-structures, powershell-5.0

I find myself continually faced with the need to store mixed-type data in some kind of a structure for later lookup.

For a recent example, I am performing data migration and I will store the old UUID, new UUID, source environment, target environment, and schema for an unknown number of entries.

I have been meeting this need by creating an array and inserting System.Objects with NoteProperty members for each of the columns of data.

This strikes me as a very clumsy approach but I feel like I may be limited by Powershell's functionality. If I need to, for example, locate all entries that used a particular schema, I write a foreach loop that sticks each entry with a matching schema name in a whole new array that I can return. I would really like the ability to more easily search for all objects that contain a member matching a particular value, modify existing members, etc.

Is there a better built-in data structure that will suit my needs, or is creating a custom object the right thing to do?

For reference, I'm doing something like this to create my structure:

```
$objectArray= @();
foreach(thing to process){
   $tempObj = New-Object System.Object;
   $tempObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "membername" -Value xxxxx
   ....repeat for each member...
   $objectArray += $tempObj
}
```

If I need to find something in it, I then have to:

```
$matchingObjs = @()
foreach ($obj in $objectArray){
    if($obj.thing -eq value){$matchingObjs += $obj}
}
```

This really sucks and I know there has to be a more elegant way. I'm still fairly new to powershell so I don't know what utilities it has to help me. I'm using v5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PowerShell 3.0 you could use a `[PSCustomObject]`, here's [an article on the different object creation methods](https://devopscollective.gitbooks.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-gotchas/content/manuscript/new-object_psobject_vs_pscustomobject.html).

Also setting the array equal to the output of the `foreach` loop will be more efficient than [repeatedly recreating](https://powershell.org/2013/09/16/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/) an array with `+=`.

```
$objectArray = foreach ($item in $collection) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "membername" = "xxxxx"
    }
}
```

The `Where-Object` cmdlet or the `.where()` method looks like what you need in your second loop.

```
$matchingObjs = $objectArray | Where-Object {$_.thing -eq "value"}
```

It also sounds like you could use `Where-Object`/`.where()` to filter the initial data and just create an object which matches what you are looking for. For example:

```
$matchingObjs = $InputData |
    Where-Object {$_.thing -eq "value"} |
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "membername" = xxxxx
        }
    }
```

If your data can be expressed as key value pairs, then a `hashtable` will be the most efficient, see `about_Hash_Tables` for more info.

Comment: Thank you - I needed to see some of the other methods of object creation and I appreciate seeing a better way to fill my object array. I didn't realize that appending objects would be handled automatically if I set the array equal to a foreach.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to do what you are asking. One way is to segment your data into separate hashtables so you can do easy lookups by a common key, say the ID.

```
# Create a hastable for the IDs
$ids = @{};
foreach(thing to process){
    $ids.Add($uid, 'Value')
}

# Find the $uid exists
$keyExists = $ids.Keys -Contains $uid

# Find value of stored for $uid
$keyValue = $ids[$uid]
```

As a side note, you don't have to create Syste.Object, you can simple do this:

```
$objectArray = @();

gci | % {
    $objectArray += @{
        'Key1' = 'Value 1'
        'Key2' = 'Value 2'
    }
}
```

If you need to compare complex objects, you can build them with @{} and then use Compare-Object on the two objects, just another idea.

For example, this will get a file listing of two different directories, and tell me what file exists or doesn't exist between the two directories:

```
$packages = (gci $boxStarterRepo -Recurse *.nuspec | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -replace '.nuspec', ''
$packages += (gci $boxStarterPrivateRepo -Recurse *.nuspec | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -replace '.nuspec', ''
$packages = $packages | Sort-Object

Compare-Object $packages $done
```

Comment: I like the idea of hashtables and it will work great for some functions but not everything. This is a great answer and has some very useful info.